# Powershell Return Object non-cmdlet

Tags: powershell

How to return an object in native? Been looking at it for awhile, no clear, easy simple examples!

[EDIT] FIXED! Just solved it on my own, correct code is below!

```
function search-member()
{
$objOU_1 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=somedomain")

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher

$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objOU_1
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(sAMAccountName=username))"
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$results = $objSearcher.FindAll()

# return $results # instead of this

$results # you first "write" what you want returned
return   # then return
}

$obj1 = search-member-2003 # if you take away the "$obj = " it will spit out the write which u have in the function directly.

$obj1 # here is the boject
```

Comment: Just answered my own question.

you must echo(write) what you want returned in the function, as it will be saved in the varible $obj1, then u may do what u want with it.

Answer (score 0):

if you change in your script this:

```
foreach ($result in $results)
{     
    $result        
}
```

or just

```
return $results
```

then

```
$obj1 = search-member
$obj1.gettype()
```

will give an `object[]` of `'SearchResult'` this if 'username' contains a wildcard like Smith* and exist at less two entry ( like 'smith' and 'smithson'). Then

`$obj1[0].gettype()` is `'SearchResult'`

if 'username' is unique `$obj1` is of  type '`SearchResult`'.